# Beamer — show current section in toc without counting as a "first page"

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use the following command,

```
\section[Gauge theory]{1) Gauge theory}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

but so that it does not consider itself as the first page of the section.

Notabley, I would like only the name of the section to be highlighted in the Singapore theme outline on the top of the slides like this
[image]

as opposed to having the first dot shaded already as I am getting here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{title}
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\miniframeson
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```